# "cross-env" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable

Tags: laravel, nodejs

Estoy intentando ejecutar el comando: `npm run watch` para compilar los archivos en laravel 5.6. Estoy usando laragon que incluye Node js 8.9.

Este es el script del error:

```
$ npm run watch

> @ watch C:\laragon\www\learning
> npm run development -- --watch


> @ development C:\laragon\www\learning
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch"

"cross-env" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch"`npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Juanzu\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-11-21T22_07_58_504Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ watch: `npm run development -- --watch`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ watch script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Juanzu\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-11-21T22_07_58_582Z-debug.log
```

Asi tengo mi archivo `package.json`:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.5",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "vue": "^2.5.7"
    }

}
```

Comment: Me paso lo mismo con `npm run dev` en *Laravel 5.8* con *Xampp*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Prueba a instalar `cross-env` como módulo global:

```
npm uninstall cross-env
```

Borra el directorio `node_modules` y asegúrate de que la línea `"cross-env": "^5.1",` ya no está en el archivo `package.json`.

```
npm install --global cross-env
npm install --no-bin-links
```

Y prueba otra vez:

```
npm run watch
```

Comment: Cuando ejecuto npm unistall cross-env me sale error: npm WARN deprecated browserslist@2.11.3: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...:"~0.0.0","webpack-de'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Juanzu\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-11-22T23_12_29_602Z-debug.log

Comment: Me sirvió, aunque me gustaría hubiese una breve explicación de por qué hacer todo ésto para que funcione de nuevo el npm run watch. Gracias de nuevo. Por favor considera agregarla, @jotaelesalinas

Comment: Si te soy sincero, yo tampoco comprendo por qué es necesario hacer esto. En mi opinión, no debería ser así. Me encontré con este problema hace tiempo y depués de googlear mucho y probar cosas, eso fue lo que funcionó.

Answer (score 2):

Asegurate de ejecutar `npm install` antes de ejecutar `npm run watch` o similar. Debes tener la carpeta "/node_modules" y si entras deberian salirte todos los paquetes que estén instalados (puedes verlo en /package.json)

Answer (score 1):

Ejecuta `npm install` si descargaste tu proyecto de git y no habías corrido anteriormente.

Esto es para configurar **node** y para que en el proyecto se descarguen los paquetes en la carpeta **node_modules** ya que por el archivo `.gitignore` estos no se encuentran en git.

Answer (score 0):

Desinstala cross-env

```
npm uninstall cross-env
```

Reinstala sin enlaces binarios.

```
npm install cross-env --no-bin-links
```

Y prueba otra vez:

```
npm run watch
```

Instalarlo de forma global lo quitará de tu proyecto de forma definitiva, no me parece buena idea porque luego ya no se instalará con tu repositorio.